# What is the good approach to get the theme colors from the server and change it in the whole android application?

Tags: android, android-theme, color-scheme

I am working on an android application in which I will get the colors and fonts from the back-end server because there is an option in admin panel to change the colors of the application. That means the admin can change the colors from his panel and I have to reflect it in the android application.

**Now, I need to show the default colors from the resource file and also need to change those color values if admin add or change the colors from his panel.**

Things I got during research:

- I have set the colors creating a themes but we cannot change the theme values at runtime.
- Storing colors in shared preferences and set them manually everywhere.

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: just get the theme color code from response and save it in session and use this color code to apply ,,, if u want to change color for anywhere you in app page you should call services to call the api , or else you can call the api at a particular screen.

Comment: @Kannanpanneerselvam thanks, but the problem is that in this case i have to make changes in the whole application where i need to change the colors. I am looking for the solution where I can control everything from one place. Like changing the theme values, which is not possible.

Comment: check my answer it may help

Comment: Thanks but the color values are not know to me to add it in the styles. we need to get it from the server.

Comment: just check my code updated. in Utils.java colorname

Comment: @Er.RohitSharma did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score -2):

```
public class ChangeThemeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

                findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
      findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
}
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      switch (v.getId())
      {
      case R.id.button1:
      Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_DEFAULT);
      break;
      case R.id.button2:
      Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_WHITE);
      break;
      case R.id.button3:
      Utils.changeToTheme(this, Utils.THEME_BLUE);
      break;
      }
 }
   }
```

Utils.java

```
public class Utils
{
 private static int sTheme;
 public final static int THEME_DEFAULT = 0;
 public final static int THEME_WHITE = 1;
 public final static int THEME_BLUE = 2;
     /**
     * Set the theme of the Activity, and restart it by creating a new Activity of 
  the 
    same type.
      */
    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
     {
      sTheme = theme;
      activity.finish();
   activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
   }
    /** Set the theme of the activity, according to the configuration. */
    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
    {
Context ctx = getContext();
      switch (sTheme)
      {
      default:
      case THEME_DEFAULT:
ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("BLUE_" + colorName, "color", 
ctx.getPackageName());

          break;

     }
```

where colorname is ur dynamic color from server

Comment: This solution is valid only where we have predefined themes in styles. But in our case, we need to get the resource values from the server, and then have to create the theme using that values.

Comment: But still BLUE_colorName should be a defined color resource in color file.

Comment: thats a reference name

Comment: I know. Suppose reference name is DARK, then the value would be BLUE_DARK. So BLUE_DARK should be defined in the color resource file so that getIdentifier can get it. Also i will get the ARGB value of the colors from the server, not the reference names.

Comment: programatically  u can set the color code to ur styles and call that identifier

Comment: Do you know how to set color code to the styles programatically? That's exactly what I want.

Comment: refer this link it may help you  https://github.com/negusoft/GreenMatter

Comment: README.md of this library says: "THIS LIB DOESN'T WORK ON ANDROID MARSHMALLOW (6.0+) AND ITS USE IS DISCOURAGED!"